# What does "frank" (noun, food-related) mean?

Tags: meaning

I found the following text in the [dictionary of soldier slang of WWII](https://www.amazon.de/FUBAR-Up-Beyond-All-Recognition-ebook/dp/B01DPPXF0I/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1514623287&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=fubar+fucket+up+beyond+any+recognition) (my emphasis):

> beans 'n' weenies: C-ration beans and **franks**, a cornerstone of infrantry nutrition

I assume that *franks* is a piece of food, but I couldn't find any food-related meaning of this word.

What does *frank* mean in this context?

Comment: Stephen Sisk's answer is correct.

Comment: @Franz Drollig - it is a pity you didn’t want to consider the different, though obscene, nuances of the term. After all you came up with an expression from military slang, which is most of times “obscene”.

Comment: @user159691 That doesn't relate to C-ration or infantry nutrition.

Comment: @Araucaria - OP asked for military slang, if the sentence is to be taken literally, it is just GR

Comment: Note that "beans and weenies" isn't particularly military (though it may have originated there).  It was a commonly served dish at e.g. church suppers and the school cafeteria when I was a kid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Franks, in *Franks and Beans* refers to FRANKfurters. *Weenies* refers to WIENERS.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beanie_Weenies) page for a picture of the dish.

And here's an excerpt from [*Dreamboat of the Western World*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=meQJ2bm_DaMC&q=%22franks+and+beans%22+%22frankfurters+and+beans%22&dq=%22franks+and+beans%22+%22frankfurters+and+beans%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg9NDuqLTYAhVC-aQKHQBODdIQ6AEIPjAE) by Tracy Sinclair (1992):

> "I also got a bottle of wine for dinner."
>
> "I hope it's an unpretentious little vintage that goes with frankfurters and beans. That's what we're having." Melissa got out two highball glasses and filled an ice bucket from the freezer.
>
> "Great. I haven't had franks and beans in a long time,"

Comment: Anything to support your assumptions?

Comment: @user159691 there's no "assumptions" it's the right answer!

Comment: @user159691 hmm, so how come you deleted your supported answer? The OP's citation is a definition `a cornerstone of infrantry nutrition`

Comment: @Mari-LouA - because it was receiving unjustified downvotes just by imitation. Btw, anyone who’s been under the Army, any Army, would understand the doble entendre. .

Comment: No @user159691 the downvotes were not unjustified. the OP asked `What does frank mean in this context?` I also DV because I thought you should have edited and clarified. I would have retracted my DV, that's how SE should work.

Answer (score 7):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has this

> **frank**<sup>3</sup>
>   noun *North American*
>   Short for FRANKFURTER

and

> **frankfurter**
>   noun
>   A seasoned smoked sausage typically made of beef and pork